# returning to macOS perl - coming from brew perl

Tags: macos, perl, homebrew

I used brew to install perl and I linked it using `brew link perl`. I'd to go back and use the macOS perl again.

I can do `brew unlink perl` but how do I correctly link the macOS perl again? After unlinking brew perl I'm missing all symlinks to use `perl`-commands.

Any help/tips for what to research is appreciated. Can't find any help for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had to start a new Terminal after unlinking. Everything works out of the box after doing `brew unlink perl`. Sorry for that.